# why does aio_write() act wrong?

Tags: asynchronous, aio, aio-write

I want to write 2 files by using aio_write.

Used 32KB buffer and repeat aio_write 2048 times for 1 file.(file size is 64MB)

However result is not 64MB but size is 64MB + 32KB, now.

Also sometimes file is written by garbage.
I want to fill 'A' to file.

Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <aio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <siginfo.h>

#define TNAME           "testAio.c"
#define BUFFER_SIZE     32 * 1024 //(32 * 1024 * 1024)
#define FILE_COUNT      2
#define FILE_PATH       256
#define FALSE           0
#define TRUE            1

int main ()
{
    char           sTmpFileName[FILE_COUNT][FILE_PATH];
    char         * sBuf;
    char         * sAlignedBuf;
    int           sFd[FILE_COUNT];
    struct aiocb  sAiocb[FILE_COUNT];
    int           sError;
    int           sRet;
    int           i;
    int           j;
    int           sWritten[FILE_COUNT];
    int           sWrittenSize;
    int           sWrittenCnt;
    int           sFrequence = 2048;

    sBuf = (char*) malloc( BUFFER_SIZE + 512 );

sAlignedBuf = (char*)( ((long)sBuf) + (512 -  ((long)sBuf) % 512));

    memset( sAlignedBuf, 0x41, BUFFER_SIZE );

    for( i = 0; i < FILE_COUNT; i++ )
    {
        memset( &sAiocb[i], 0, sizeof(struct aiocb) );

        sAiocb[i].aio_buf = sAlignedBuf;
        sAiocb[i].aio_nbytes = BUFFER_SIZE;

        snprintf( sTmpFileName[i],
                  FILE_PATH,
                  "testAio_%d",
                  i);

        unlink( sTmpFileName[i] );

        sFd[i] = open( sTmpFileName[i],
                       O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_EXCL |
                       O_DIRECT | O_LARGEFILE,
                       S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR );

        sAiocb[i].aio_fildes = sFd[i];

        if( sFd[i] == -1 )
        {
            printf( TNAME " Error at open(): %s\n", strerror( errno ) );
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    for( j = 0; j < sFrequence; j++ )
    {
        for( i = 0; i < FILE_COUNT; i++ )
        {
            if( sWrittenSize = aio_write( &sAiocb[i] ) == -1 )
            {
                printf( TNAME " Error at aio_write(): %s\n", strerror( errno ) );

                close( sFd[i] );

                exit(2);
            }

            sAiocb[i].aio_offset += sAiocb[i].aio_nbytes;

            // printf( "offset %ld\n", sAiocb[i].aio_offset );
        }
    }

    printf( "offset %ld %ld\n",
            sAiocb[0].aio_offset,
            sAiocb[1].aio_offset );

    /* Wait until completion */
    i = 0;
    sWritten[0] = FALSE;
    sWritten[1] = FALSE;
    sWrittenCnt = 0;
    while( 1 )
    {
        sError = aio_error( &sAiocb[i] );

        if( sError != EINPROGRESS )
        {
            if( sWritten[i] == FALSE )
            {
                sWrittenCnt++;
                sWritten[i] = TRUE;
            }
        }

        if( sWrittenCnt == FILE_COUNT )
        {
            break;
        }

        i = (i + 1) % FILE_COUNT;
    }


    for( i = 0; i < FILE_COUNT; i++ )
    {
        sError = aio_error( &sAiocb[i] );
        sRet = aio_return( &sAiocb[i] );

        if( sError != 0 )
        {

            printf( TNAME " Error at aio_error() : %d, %s\n",
                    i,
                    strerror( sError ) );

            close( sFd[i] );

            exit(2);
        }

        if( sRet != BUFFER_SIZE )
        {
            printf( TNAME " Error at aio_return()\n" );

            close( sFd[i] );

            exit(2);
        }
    }

    for( i = 0; i < FILE_COUNT; i++ )
    {
        close( sFd[i] );
    }

    printf( "Test PASSED\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most POSIX implementations enforce severe limits on the number of concurrent asynchronous i/o operations which can be in flight in total on the system, and per process. This limit is 16 on some major implementations. You therefore cannot simply call `aio_write` 2048 times in sequence, you must call it only up until `AIO_LISTIO_MAX` which is the maximum possible, always checking error codes for system resource exhaustion before that maximum possible limit. Even on NT which has no hard limits, performance noticeably nosedives after a certain amount of concurrency when `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` is on, especially on older Windows kernels.

Once you have scheduled as many `aio_write` as the system will take, you then need to call `aio_suspend` on what you've scheduled and retire out any ops which complete, trying again to refill the pending i/o queue. If you'd like to see a production example of usage, try https://github.com/ned14/boost.afio/blob/master/include/boost/afio/v2.0/detail/impl/posix/io_service.ipp.

I should emphasise that POSIX aio scales poorly, provides virtually no performance benefit, and on Linux or FreeBSD your "asynchronous i/o" is really a thread pool of workers which call the synchronous i/o APIs for you. Virtually no POSIX OS implements much asynchronicity in practice unless `O_DIRECT` or its equivalent is turned on, it's only really worth bothering with on NT.

As many other posts on Stackoverflow have said, async filesystem i/o is not worth the time nor hassle for 99% of users, just use a thread pool calling the synchronous APIs instead, it scales far far better and is portable across all platforms, doesn't have daft problems with signals, plus always on Linux or on FreeBSD when `O_DIRECT` is off it's how POSIX aio is implemented anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

Now I have other problem.

I reduced repeating time from 2048 to 10 and 32K to 8K. 
So total calling time aio_write() is just 20.
File was filled with garbage and last part has 8K 'A'
and then size was same as 11 repeating time.

If I need to use aio_susped() for OS resource, I will do it. 
But problem does not seem to be about resource.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment.
 
Now I noticed about the code that I made mistake.

I don't know whether it is certain or not.
I assume that aio_nbytes should be handled concurrently.

After I called aio_write for certain file(ex file1), I have to wait until end of the call for next aio_write call for file1.

Is my assumption right?